# Straight wire producing a magnetic field of 1T?

Tags: magnetic-fields

Sorry if this question is silly, but in the project that I am working on, I need a current carrying straight wire to produce a magnetic field of 1 Tesla. I need to know if this actually realistic. I've searched online but found nothing.

It could  be one single conductor or multiple thin wires carrying current. If it is somehow possible, what would be the best method to do it?

Comment: Does this help: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/magnetic/magcur.html

Comment: I know how the magnetic field is produced and how strong it is, but my question is how feasible is it to produce such high currents and if there are other methods.

Answer (score 1):

The magnetic field strength at a distance $r$ from a wire carrying a current $I$ is given by:

$$ B = \frac{\mu_0 I}{2\pi r} $$

To get a field strength of one tesla at a distance of one cm would require a current of $50,000$ amps. This doesn't seem very feasible.

Comment: what about multiple wires in the same direction? would that change anything?

Comment: A bundle of 50 wires each carrying 1000 A would give you the same field, but, you'd still have the same heat dissipation problems as for the single wire carrying 50 000 A.

Comment: assuming we got around heat dissipation,  is it feasible to produce 50 wires with 1000 Amps of current, because I've never seen it being done before and if it is how should I do it?

Comment: @Chandrahas the LHC magnets only use a current of $11,700$ amps and they are miracles of engineering. You have absolutely no chance of producing the field you want from a straight wire without the resources of an organisation the size of CERN behind you.

Comment: Thanks, Got it, but why can a coil produce such large fields, wouldn't that need a higher potential difference due to the large resistance? So is the problem with the straight wire configuration maintaining the potential difference because the current (the flow of charge) quickly neutralizes it? Thanks